# Can I use the ftw-function for class methods in C++?

Tags: c++, linux

I would like to use the [ftw-function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//functions/ftw.html) to recursivly traverse a filesystem structure. Additionally, the method shall be used inside of a class. Also, the entry-function, which is called by nftw(), belongs to the same class. That needs to be the case because the entry-function is supposed to change some class-members, dependent on the files that it finds.

When implementing such an approach, I get an error (see below). Is this an issue of syntax or is it not even possible to forward a pointer to a method to nftw()? In case it is not possible, do you know any alternative way to resursivly traverse a filesystem structure under linux?

```
class model
{
  public:
    boost::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;

    int configure(const char *name)
    {
        // ...
        ftw("DTModels/", this->ftw_entry, 15);
        // ...

        return = 0;
    }


  private:

    int ftw_entry(const char *filepath, const struct stat *info, const int typeflag)
    {
        // Here I want to change the member 'map'
        std::string filepath_s = filepath;
        std::cout << "FTW_Entry: " << filepath_s << std::endl;
    }
};


ERROR:
a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function
      ftw("DTModels/", this->ftw_entry, 15);
```

Comment: a member function pointer is different from a function pointer as you need an instance to call a member function. There must be lots of duplicate questions around, maybe you find something if you search for "member function pointer"

Comment: yes, but every time the function configure() is called, that happens because somewhere else in the code the function configure() is called through a specific object with type "model". Hence, when "being" in the function configure(), I should be able to make a function pointer to "my own" member function ftw_entry(), i.e. this->ftw_entry. What I suspect the error to be is that maybe the Linux-function ftw() does not accept a "member function pointer". What do you think?

Comment: there is no "but". You need an instance to call a member function. `ftw` expects a `int (*fn)(const char *,const struct stat *ptr, int flag)` which is a different type than your member function. One solution would be to make `ftw_entry` a free function and change the member `filepath` already in `configure`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `ftw` in many many years and since you ask for an alternative, take a look at `std::filesystem` (C++17). Many pre-C++17 installations have it available via `boost` or `experimental`. If you use one of the pre-C++17 implementations, you many need to remove some of the `stat` lines from the below to make it work.

```
#include <iostream>

//#define I_HAVE_BOOST

#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
  #include <filesystem>
  namespace fs = std::filesystem;
#elif I_HAVE_BOOST
  #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
  namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
#else
  #include <experimental/filesystem>
  namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
#endif

auto& out = std::cout;

void show_dent(const fs::directory_entry& dent) {
    static size_t indent=0;
    std::string ind(indent, ' ');

    fs::file_status lstat = dent.symlink_status();

    if( fs::is_symlink(lstat) ) {
        fs::path pp = fs::read_symlink(dent);
        out << ind << dent << " -> " << pp << "\n";
        ++indent;
        show_dent(fs::directory_entry(pp));
        --indent;
    } else {
        if(fs::is_directory(dent)) {
            fs::directory_iterator dit_end;

            std::cout << "Directory " << dent << " includes the following files:\n";
            ++indent;
            for(auto dit = fs::directory_iterator(dent); dit != dit_end; ++dit) {
                show_dent(*dit);
            }
            --indent;
        } else {
            fs::file_status stat = dent.status();

            out << ind << dent << "\n"
                << ind << " stat\n"
                << ind << "  is_regular_file  : " << fs::is_regular_file(stat) << "\n"
                << ind << "  is_directory     : " << fs::is_directory(stat) << "\n"
                << ind << "  is_block_file    : " << fs::is_block_file(stat) << "\n"
                << ind << "  is_character_file: " << fs::is_character_file(stat) << "\n"
                << ind << "  is_fifo          : " << fs::is_fifo(stat) << "\n"
                << ind << "  is_socket        : " << fs::is_socket(stat) << "\n"
                << ind << "  is_symlink       : " << fs::is_symlink(stat) << "\n"
                << ind << "  exists           : " << fs::exists(stat) << "\n";
            if( fs::is_regular_file(stat) ) {
                out
                << ind << "  file_size        : " << fs::file_size(dent) << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);

    out << std::boolalpha;

    for(const auto& file_or_dir : args) {
        show_dent(fs::directory_entry(file_or_dir));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How will this work in the cases when the entries are moved, renamed, deleted while the traversal happens? What'll happen if the tree has too large nesting level? All this is handled by `nftw` and `ftw` functions, which the OP was asking about, while I suppose the implementation you propose won't work normally in at least some of these situations. Making it work correctly is re-inventing `ftw`/`nftw`. So it's not a valid alternative.

Comment: I haven't looked at the actual implementation of `std::filesystem` so I can't answer all those questions I'm afraid, but  "_If a file or a directory is deleted or added to the directory tree after the directory iterator has been created, it is unspecified whether the change would be observed through the iterator_" and I expect (but can't confirm) that `std::filesystem` uses the low-level OS APIs for directory traversal so that running out of file descriptors etc. won't be a problem. Just speculation on my part though.